# Can UIAutomator be used remotely?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I want to use UIAutomator's functionality inside my java application which runs on a computer connected to an Android device. Is this possible?

I've looked at monkeyrunner/chimpchat but UIAutomator seems to provide significantly more functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if your device is rooted - you can then just run the same uiautomator runtest command that you would from an adb shell.

[See my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561071/1684866)

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at https://github.com/xiaocong/android-uiautomator-jsonrpcserver. You can write PC side script to communicate with uiautomator jsonrpc server. I am also writing a [python wrapper module](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator) to use it. It's not java, but you can read code for how it communicates with the jsonrpc server.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [UiMutilator](https://github.com/vidstige/UiMutilator) to run tests on your machine locally and have them executed on Android, either emulator or real device.

I developed this in order to be able to run simple TestNG tests and run them conveniently from Eclipse. The [UiMutilator](https://github.com/vidstige/UiMutilator) only supports a subset of what the UiAutomator does, but if it covers your needs it might be a nice option.