# Is it possible to make an API call in UI Automator Android

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I tried to make an api call in UI Automator android. My code is posted below. Can we make an API call like this :

```
    String enter_url = "www.abc.com";
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Enter URL or Search & Win")).setText(enter_url);
    getUiDevice().click(745, 969);

    //calling check class
    new check().execute(enter_url);     

//AsyncTask 
private class check extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String myurl = args[0];

          //making api call here


    // the json string is stored here
        String result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Result is :" + result);
        return result;  

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't.

If you have root you could call UiAutomator from and Android application though: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17561071/1684866)